# Debugging a deadlock with ReaderWriterLockSlim

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, debugging, windbg

I am debugging a hang in a managed application targeted .NET 3.5. One of the threads is waiting forever for the method `System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim.EnterWriteLock`. To find out what thread owns the lock I inspected the [internal member field ReaderWriterCount[] rwc](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/untmp/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/fx/src/Core/System/Threading/ReaderWriterLockSlim/ReaderWriterLockSlim@cs/1305376/ReaderWriterLockSlim@cs) of `ReaderWriterLockSlim` class and all the `ReaderWriterCount` and `RecursiveCounts` objects it contains. These objects contains the info about all the threads. All the objects contained `writercount=0` and `readercount=0` except the single one that contained `readercount=1`:

```
[53] 0144fc84
    Name: System.Threading.ReaderWriterCount
    MethodTable: 6bb4e930
    EEClass: 6b9ba4d0
    Size: 24(0x18) bytes
     (C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll)
    Fields:
          MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr    Value Name
    55782f94  4000625        c         System.Int32  1 instance       53 threadid
    55782f94  4000626       10         System.Int32  1 instance        1 readercount
    6bb4e930  4000627        4 ...ReaderWriterCount  0 instance 00000000 next
    6bb4e858  4000628        8 ...g.RecursiveCounts  0 instance 0144fc9c rc
```

AFAIU it means that thread with MTID 53 is owning the lock. I dumped it stack with kb (!clrstack failed as it is not a managed thread) and got the following:

```
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
16eee9b4 765c14ab 00000280 00000000 16eee9fc ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0x15
16eeea20 778d1194 00000280 00009c40 00000000 KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x98
16eeea38 681954d7 00000280 00009c40 00000000 KERNEL32!WaitForSingleObjectExImplementation+0x75
16eeea7c 68195423 00000280 00009c40 00000000 mscorwks!PEImage::LoadImage+0x1af
16eeeacc 68195442 00009c40 00000000 00000000 mscorwks!CLREvent::WaitEx+0x117
16eeeae0 681d95c7 00009c40 00000000 00000000 mscorwks!CLREvent::Wait+0x17
16eeeb60 681d9a55 03376058 00009c40 00000000 mscorwks!ThreadpoolMgr::SafeWait+0x73
16eeebc4 68226508 00000000 00000000 00000000 mscorwks!ThreadpoolMgr::WorkerThreadStart+0x11c
16eefa64 778d338a 04b2e5c8 16eefab0 77e09f72 mscorwks!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+0x49
16eefa70 77e09f72 04b2e5c8 6aecf560 00000000 KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
16eefab0 77e09f45 682264c2 04b2e5c8 00000000 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x70
16eefac8 00000000 682264c2 04b2e5c8 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b
```

Which means that it is an [Idle CLR Worker Thread](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2007/04/02/things-to-ignore-when-debugging-an-asp-net-hang-update-for-net-2-0.aspx).

My first thought was there is a bug in the application code when the reader lock is not always released. But the hypothesis didn't confirmed as the code uses wrapper on ReaderWriterLockSlim.EnterWriteLock which looks like this:

```
readerWriterLockSlim.EnterReadLock();

try
{
    return executeFunc();
}
finally
{
    readerWriterLockSlim.ExitReadLock();
}
```

The `finally` block must guarantee that the lock will always be released.

Any thoughts how this situation is possible? Could the thread somehow be aborted after the lock acquisition but before `finally` and then become an idle thread pool thread? May be tips how to narrow the problem?

P.S. This deadlock was reproduced only once and I am only have a memory dump hence I cannot easily say add traces or breakpoints around the locks and experiment with this.

Comment: @usr My experiments show that in case of reentrancy `readercount` would be equal to `2` or greater...

Comment: And the lock is recursive.

Answer (score 1):

Try !sosex.dlk and/or !mlocks and !mwaits.  This should show you what is going on.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But these commands gave me exactly the same info I described just in a simpler way. An idle thread pool thread is holding a read lock and blocks to proceed the other.

Comment: Sorry.  I've read your post more carefully and this does look strange.  Are you sure that the code snippet you posted is the only code that takes a read lock on this lock?  If so, then I cannot explain this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

It might be that you are having asynchronous exceptions (like thread abort) that skip the finally block of code.
You can find more about it [here](http://joeduffyblog.com/2007/02/07/introducing-the-new-readerwriterlockslim-in-orcas/) under section **Some limitations: reliability**.